# How to get started with designing a user interface: build components or pages?

Tags: design, prototype

It seems a UI designer starts by making a bunch of components a developer can put together like a jigsaw to create pages. Once the components have all been designed, the UI designer can move on to a prototype of a whole page.

How can you create a bunch of components when you have no idea of what the page will look like? Who would even want a bunch of components / a "UI kit" when they have no idea of how a page would look?

Answer (score 1):

I happens exactly the opposite way. User goals, and not components, drives the flows and screens.

Start by researching what your user is trying to do, what do they need, what they are looking for, what pain points they have, user journeys, etc. Those behavior trends and product goals will drive your task flow and screen needs. Without this, there is no UX. Without this, the designs will be templated and directionless with no purpose.

Only after you have designed the screens, you can start thinking about components. And this is really only applicable to larger more complex application ecosystems.

There must be an ROI to composing a component library (e.g. you ecosystems of applications is becoming so large that branding is inconsistent, developers and designers are doing repeat work, there are multiple versions of the same component, etc).

If you can justify the effort, then the component library / design system development starts. This is generally a process of systematizing components which starts with an audit of all the components you have across all applications, grouping them, merging similarities and functionality, discussing with dev, design, etc, questioning and re-questioning the purpose of each component.

The result is a consistency library used across your products so everything is consistent, from branding, voice and tone, coding, design, etc. It has rules of when and where to use, etc. All that knowledge stems from the endless discussions when composing the library. Also, the library is constantly updated for every new features the product might have. Find examples here - https://designsystemsrepo.com/design-systems/

I think the "defining components first" stems from the misconception of "defining features first". How can anyone define what a product should or should not have based on zero understanding of the user it's intended for?

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches you could take, depending on your resources and time and what your stakeholders need:

1. Sign up for a system like [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/) and use their deliberately lo-fi components to design the basic structure of the pages while your team continues working on the larger look and feel. You can also keep your page designs lo-fi in whatever system you're using (Figma, Sketch, Adobe XD, etc.)
2. Or, if lo-fi won't work with your stakeholders and they need hi-fi immediately, you can find a free or paid component library at a site like [UI8](https://ui8.net/categories/ui-kits) and download their UI kits and build with them.

I strongly urge trying to go with 1 while you take a look at 2, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to write, edit, write, edit, ...

What is the purpose of the app? What information is displayed to the user? What  information does the user provide? Break it down for each screen. What buttons are required.  What happens when each button is tapped?  Etc, etc, etc,

Understand your application first.  It is the hard part.  Get it right and you will save time and money.

Answer (score -1):

Before thinking about building the page first or component, you can determine what the page will look like based on its functionality. The functionality will guide the information architecture for the page. For e.g. if it is a Q&A forum, then you would think about laying info accordingly etc.

- For a big app/ project, when you make the wireframes/ lo fi mocks for the screens you will know the components that are recurring apart from the 'Atoms' [buttons, dropdowns, checkboxes etc.] and those components will be part of the component library. Wireframes can be made in any tool like Figma/ Sketch/ Balsamiq etc. Based on the scale of the project, you could choose to use a well documented library - ant/ material/ bootstrap or define your own components ground up.
- Another point to note is that everything is not a part of component library. Some pages require custom frontend to be written. Something is turned into a component if it is going to be used multiple times.